# Error of logcat in Eclipse

Tags: java, android

What is mean of the this message in logcat:

> ERROR : timer_thread: tick delayed > 5 slots (-54881391,-50000000) -- cpu overload ? ##### –

My application has been stopped and does not run. What is the problem here?

Comment: I corrected some spelling. Please be a bit more specific. Did your application stop *because* this error or does this error occur *despite* your app was already stopped? Also, you should try to find the part of your code causing the problem (using a debugger and break points) and show it to us.

Comment: It's unclear that this message has anything at all to do with your app or its problems (typical Android device logs are sadly full of spurious content), but even if it does, unless you have an app full of silent catch blocks, this is not the most informative of the log messages that are being generated.  Look at the others, and include them in the body of your question.